# Django with a list of primary key in detail view

Tags: python, django

In my program, the index page shows a list of products in a table with a checkbox in each rows, and a dropdown list of the price level (for example: Retail, Distributor)
When the user selects the price level and multiple products by checking the checkboxes, they click process and the program with run a query based on the selected items and selected price levels

So, it has 2 views: index view which lists everything and detail view which just lists whatever selected. The index view is the view that has the POST button and is where I capture the selected price level and selected items. These parameters will be passed over the detail view using the return redirect.

The problem I have is the URLConfig url.py

In the detail views, there are 2 parameters passing in: the selected price level and selected items. With the selected price level, I have no issue capturing it as it's a single value: either Retail or Distributor. The selected items is the problem: I don't know how to pass an array of selected items in the URL Config.

The path should be like this
/detail/Retail/{product A, product B, product C}

Here is what I got so far

path('detail/',views.detail,name = 'detail')

This is the error message

Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'pricelevel_id': '1', 'selected_items': ['2', '7', '5']}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['pricequotation\/detail\/(?P[0-9]+)$']

Here is my index view:

```
def index(request):
item = Item.objects.all().order_by('category','description','unitofmeasure')
pricelevels = get_list_or_404(PriceLevel)

if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_pricelevel = request.POST['selected_pricelevel']
    print (selected_pricelevel)
    return redirect('pricequotation:detail', pricelevel_id = selected_pricelevel)
else:
    return render(request,"index.html",context={'item':item,'pricelevels':pricelevels})
```

Here is my detail view:

```
def detail(request,pricelevel_id):
selected_pricelevel = get_object_or_404(PriceLevel,pk=pricelevel_id)

pricelevelperitem = PriceLevelPerItem.objects.filter(pricelevel__name__contains=selected_pricelevel).order_by('item__description','item__name')
return render(request,"detail.html",context={'pricelevelperitem':pricelevelperitem,'selected_pricelevel':selected_pricelevel})
```

Comment: Why don't you use POST method (not GET - assuming you're submitting data to the view) to submit your form so you don't have so include your parameters in the actual url?

Comment: can you please give more details how to implement this?

Comment: Added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript client you'll have something like:

```
     var arr = {
         "pricelevel_id": "1", 
         "selected_items": ["2", "7", "5"]}

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://yourdomain.com/detail/Retail/",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
           console.log('success with '+data);
        },
        error: function(data){
           console.log("failure with "+data);
       }
     });
```

And then your Django view:

```
def detail(request):
    pricelevel_id =  request.data['pricelevel_id']
    selected_items = request.data['selected_items']
    # Any processing logic you may have goes here
```